# How to tidy up too many if statements for readability

Tags: if-statement, coding-style

I have an example of some code that I see often in websites that I'd like to improve and would appreciate some help. Often I see 5-10 nested if-statements in a page_load method which aim to eliminate invalid user input, but this looks ugly and is hard to read and maintain.

How would you recommend cleaning up the following code example? The main thing I'm trying to eliminate is the nested if statements.

```
string userid = Request.QueryString["userid"];

if (userid != ""){
    user = new user(userid);

    if (user != null){
        if (user.hasAccess){
            //etc.
        }
        else{
            denyAccess(INVALID_ACCESS);
        }
    }
    else{
        denyAccess(INVALID_USER);
    }
}
else{
    denyAccess(INVALID_PARAMETER);
}
```

As you can see, this gets quite messy very quickly! Are there any patterns or practices that I should be following in this case?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By using `Guard Clauses` sir

```
string userid = Reuest.QueryString["userid"];

if(userid==null)
 return denyAccess(INVALID_PARAMETER);

user = new user(userid);
if(user==null)
 return denyAccess(INVALID_USER);

if (!user.hasAccess)
 return denyAccess(INVALID_ACCESS);

//do stuff
```

PS. use either return or throw an error

Comment: Wont reach that case since there is a user==null case on top of it sir

Comment: The case of user == null is already checked.  The order of which the statements are written is significant. You have to start by checking objects for null, then illegal values etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean up the nesting a bit by negating the conditions and write an if-else chain:

```
string userid = Reuest.QueryString["userid"];

if (userid == "") {
    denyAccess(INVALID_PARAMETER);

} else if (null == (user = new user(userid))){
    denyAccess(INVALID_USER);

} else if (!user.hasAccess){
    denyAccess(INVALID_ACCESS);

} else {
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach actually. I like it because you remove the need for multiple return-statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Better to split it into multiple methods(functions) .It will be easy to understand.If some new person reads the code he/she understands the logic just by reading the method name itself(Note: Method name should express what test it does).Sample code :

```
string userid = Request.QueryString["userid"];

if(isValidParameter(userId)){
  User user=new User(userId);
    if(isValidUser(user)&&isUserHasAccess(user)){
      //Do whatever you want
     }
}

private boolean isUserHasAccess(User user){
    if (user.hasAccess){
       return true;
    }else{
        denyAccess(INVALID_ACCESS);
       return false;
    }
}

 private boolean isValidUser(User user){
    if(user !=null){
      return true;
    }else{
    denyAccess(INVALID_USER);
    return false;
    }
 }


 private boolean isValidParameter(String userId){
    if(userid !=""){
      return true;
    }else{
 denyAccess(INVALID_PARAMETER);
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea I think. Do you have an example of how this might help end the execution of the current method?